# Error in HomePage class caused by: No Provider for NavController

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to open ListPage from a button in my Google Maps marker.

[image]

1)

```
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
```

2)

```
constructor(public connectivityService: Connectivity, public navCtrl: NavController) {

      }
```

3)

```
infowindow.setContent('<button style="font-size: 1.5em; color: red; font-weight: bold;" ion-button (click)="showlistPage()">ADD BLOOD</button>' + "</br>" + results[1].formatted_address+'<p style="color: red;">'+distanceToYou+" miles from your location</p>");
```

5)

```
  showlistPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ListPage);
}
```

but now I'm getting this error: **homepage caused by no provider for navcontroller**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough It's a bad practice I tried to access a page from a service (that is Google Maps in this situation)

```
import {NavController, App} from "ionic-angular";
.....

@Injectable()
 export class GoogleMaps {

private nav:NavController;

.....

constructor(public connectivityService: Connectivity, private app:App) {

 this.nav = app.getActiveNav();

}

.....

//in my Google Maps Marker I defined the button

infowindow.setContent('<button style="font-size: 1.5em; color: red; font-weight: bold;" ion-button (click)="showlistPage()">ADD BLOOD</button>' + "</br>" + results[1].formatted_address+'<p style="color: red;">'+distanceToYou+" miles from your location</p>");

.....


showlistPage() {
  this.nav.push(ListPage);
}
```

I **still can't access the ListPage** from that button, but atleast I solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the service Connectivity in your app.module as provider, and do not forget to import it in your Component

Comment: it's already in my app.module

`providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, Locations, GoogleMaps, Connectivity]`

`import { Connectivity } from '../providers/connectivity';`

Answer (score 0):

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';   // app.module.ts file

At the bottom of the app.module.ts file add below code.

providers: [NavController,{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]